# Change default directory in cPanel

Tags: wordpress, view, directory, cpanel, default

I want to change default page in cPanel, as I created one folder and kept all WordPress files in it so by default it should open files from that folder and should show

Answer (score 0):

you can use dublicator or updraft+ its very easy to use if you're confused. You can backup from one place and install to the other.